# How to deploy my gradle web app to tomcat using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I'm trying to understand the way gradle work with eclipse.

I can't figure out how to add my webb app to the tomcat server. It does not appear.

Some mention cargo plugin but i can't get it to work either.

Here are my plugins :

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39497951/2418306

Answer (score 0):

May be I am late in joining the party but it may help some one else.

Actually there is no need for  `apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'.

A cargo plugin is useful for deploying application using gradle.

Some incites from cargo documentation:

> The plugin provides deployment capabilities for web applications to
>   local and remote containers in any given Gradle build by leveraging
>   the Cargo Ant tasks. The plugin supports WAR and EAR artifacts.

Starting with technical parts:

Step 1: You need to add the below two imports in your gradle scripts. It will enable the cargo plugin for your build.

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
```

Step 2: Specify the dependencies in your buildscripts

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.2.3'
         classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.1'

    }
}
```

Step 3: Add the dependencies for the tomcat and cargo

```
dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.47'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"

    def cargoVersion = '1.4.5'
    cargo ("org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:$cargoVersion",
          "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:$cargoVersion")
}
```

Step 4: Download the tomcat zip file and extract it in some folder in your local. Add the following code to your build.gradle

```
cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'
    port = 9090

    deployable {

        file = new File('C:/<path-to-your-war-file>/gradleTutorial.war')
        context = 'gradleTutorial'
    }

    local {
        homeDir = file('C:/<path-to-the-extracted-tomcat-folder>/tomcat-7.0.47')
        outputFile = file('build/output.log')
        timeout = 60000

        containerProperties {
            property 'cargo.tomcat.ajp.port', 9099
        }
    }   
}
```

Step 4: configure your tomcat as follows:

```
tomcat {
    httpPort = 9090
    httpsPort = 9091
    enableSSL = true
    contextPath = 'gradleTutorial'

}
```

Thats all. Once these steps are done. You must need to install gradle plugin in your eclipse from market place and you can configure as below screenshot

[Eclipse configuration sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVkVQ.png)

Enjoy...!!!!!